# Why is CAM not showing in the ICP catalog?

Tags: ibm-cloud-private, cloud-automation-manager

I have noticed that my ICP catalog is not even loading anymore. The Catalog just spins a blue circle and now when I try to perform CLI:

```
bx pr load-ppa-archive ...
```

it is throwing an error 500 response.

```
Uploading helm charts   
Processing chart: charts/ibm-cam-prod-1.0.1.tgz   
Updating chart values.yaml   
Uploading chart FAILED Returned status 500 Internal Server Error
```

What has happened?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Check cloudant connection:

   - `curl https://cloudantdb:6954/_up` in the pod to verify the status
   - check for `{"status":"ok"}` - Successful connection
2. Remove helm-repo pod and helm-api pod and wait for them to respawn to see if that fixes the issue with the ICP Catalog.